# Asp.Net Core Формы

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть форма, с помощью которого хочу отправить `string`, но когда нажимаю на `button`, то `string`, которую я ввел в `input`, не отправляется.

Что делать?

```
<form asp-action="Delete" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <tr>
        <td>Delete Event</td>
        <td> <input asp-form = "Tittle" type = "text" name = "Title" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <td colspan = "1"><input type = "submit" value = "Delete Event" /></td>
</form>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Delete()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    public string Delete(string envet)
    {
        if (envet != null)
        {
            return "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: "string которую я ввел в input не отправляется" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: с помощью Debug

Comment: Что такое "envet"?

Comment: просто название

Comment: Что Вы сделали с помощью "Debug"?

Comment: "Просто название" не бывает. Название чего?

Comment: посмотрел отправляется или нет мой string ,  и в controller приходит null

Comment: там должен быть event

Comment: `event` и `envet` - это разные вещи. Еще раз повторяю вопрос: откуда должно взяться значение параметра `envet`?

Comment: я знаю что разные вещи , просто ошибся ,  когда в input пишу значение(string) и потом нажимаю на button в controller приходит null

Comment: Вы - партизан? Мне нужно из Вас каждое слово клещами вытаскивать? Где Вы ошиблись - в Вашем коде или в вопросе? Если в вопросе, отредактируйте его - ссылка "править" под вопросом. В том html-е, который Вы показали, нет input-а с именем `"event"`, поэтому значению параметра неоткуда взяться, поэтому параметр - `null`.

Comment: спасибо большое уже решил проблему

Comment: Хорошо. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В html-форме у инпута замените `name="Title"` на `name="envet"`.
**Либо** же наоборот в контроллере имя параметра поменяйте на "Title".

Рекомендую почитать про привязку модели (model binding) [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

P.S. Что это за тег хелпер такой - `asp-form`? Сомневаюсь, что это ваш собственный, скорее всего опечатка.